# Interpreting the IIS8 failed request tracing log (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2012, iis-8, orchardcms-1.6

I am trying to setup my orchard site in a windows server 2012 IIS 8 environment. I have enabled the failed request tracing for the server. I have copied the files to the wwwroot folder and converted it to an application (by right clicking on the node and choosing "Convert to Application"). When I try to navigate to the site in the browser. I get a blank page and when I check the failed request tracing log I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='freb.xsl'?>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<failedRequest url="http://localhost:80/MySite"
           siteId="1"
           appPoolId="DefaultAppPool"
           processId="3780"
           verb="GET"
           authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE" activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-0600-0080000000FE}"
           failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
           statusCode="500.19"
           triggerStatusCode="500.19"
           timeTaken="0"
           xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
           >
</failedRequest>
```

So the question is how do I interpret this above information. I searched for the 500.19 error, it was suggested that, this error might be caused by all the required modules not being installed. I checked that, but I have all the required module installed. Where do I start debugging this error?